# Set the text and style of TD element at x (column) and y(row) for a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the row and column saved in my database as X and Y.
Is there a simple line of code that lets me set the text of the td element at a certain position in a table ?

I tried

```
$('#sTab tr:eq('racks[i].punkt.y') td:eq('racks[i].punkt.x')').html();
```

Comment: What you've got should in principle work if you have the element ID, tagnames etc correct, and the object properties you're using contains the right numbers.

Comment: @adeneo and then i would have to change .html to .text or .style?

Comment: Yes, just try something like `$(your_selector).css('background', 'red')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use some nth-child logic to do what you're looking for.